# pull specific data from string with PHP

Tags: php

Let say I have a string like this

```
sometext<br>sometext<br>sometext(Rating 50)<br>sometext<br>
```

All I want to get from this string is the "50" right after the "Rating". The number can range from 1 to 3 digits long.

Can I use something like preg_replace? explode? not sure how to get it.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\(Rating (\d+)\)/','$1',$thestring);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "sometext<br>sometext<br>sometext(Rating 50)<br>sometext<br>";
preg_match('/\(Rating (\d+)\)/',$str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: If Sudhir's answer worked for you consider accepting it via the tick left of the answer. This way, people are more likely to answer your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` to get individual components and then search for `"Rating"`. Then `50` will be the element after `"Rating"`. Of course, if you are going to use similar routine frequently, it's better to make a helper function that you could use repeatedly.

But be aware that, this will only work for the first occurrence of the string you are looking for.

Perhaps, there is an elegant solution involving `Regular Expressions` as opposed to creating an intermediate array and looping.